# Adobe AIR : Check/Alert/Prompt when user press computer shut down down or command

Tags: adobe, air

Is that possible to achieve using Adobe Air or any other suggestion? I have an app which record user time and to prevent user don't forget i think similar solution will work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a listener to close event for the application. When OS received shut down command, it'll try to terminate processes so your app will trigger close event. I haven't tested but hopefully this will work. At that moment, you can register user's session data. That's what other software do when you want to turn off, a little delay...